# vaadin combobox angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, combobox, vaadin-elements

im using vaadin combo box for angular 2

and in my html code,

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                        <vaadin-combo-box [(value)]="storecard1" label="Store Code" [items]="concept" item-label-path="MAP_Code"></vaadin-combo-box>
                    </div>
```

and in my component i put this code in string

```
    constructor(
this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://192.168.1.40:5000/getdataemp','POST',{cardno:newValue},null).subscribe((data)=>{ 

                    var rData = [];
                    for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    rData.push(data[i]);
                    }
                    var store = rData.map(i=>(i.Store_ID)).toString();

                    this.storecard1 = store; << this part cant show the value to the combobox, its still make the combobox empty

            });
)
```

but in my html its not working,

there no changing in the ui

Comment: See: https://vaadin.com/vaadin-documentation-portlet/elements/angular2-polymer/api.html

Comment: well i try that also still not working

Answer (score 0):

Most Polymer Elements don't render correctly in Angular 2. See this adapter to get your elements to work with Angular: https://github.com/platosha/angular-polymer